# Can I change the price of inapp purchase in flutter?

Tags: flutter, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect, google-play-console

I want to lower the price to some specific consumers for open promotion. I'm thinking of using promo code or email check.

For example,

```
if(*coupon code entered*)
   new_subscription_price = original_subsciption_price * 0.5;
```

or,

```
if(*email is end with .edu*) //unknown@unknown.edu
   new_subscription_price = original_subsciption_price * 0.5;
```

Is there any possible way to change price only for specific consumer? I use flutter, both google and ios platform. If it is possible, how it works?

Answer (score 0):

You can generate promo codes from [Google Play console](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/promo) & [App store connect](https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/dev1e322b132), and give these codes to your favorite customers, but there is limits on how many codes you can create.